# Undefined Component - Stack Trace Debugging?

Tags: magento2, debugging, exception, component

I'm fairly new to magento2 and trying to fix a broken extension.

I'm having a lot of trouble with stack traces, I'm not sure if it's just the way magento is or if it's because of reflection making it more abstract, but just by reading the stack I'm not able to figure out which file an error takes place in.

Example: If i go to the catalog and try to add a new product of the type this extension provides (it's a gift card extension),

It throws an error and dies.

The stack trace looks like this.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:112:"The requested component ("giftcard_price_selector") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.";i:1;s:8841:"#0 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Provider\Component\Definition->getComponentData('giftcard_price_...')
#1 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(187): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->createRawComponentData('giftcard_price_...')
#2 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(82): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('giftcard_price_...', 'giftcard_price_...', Array)
#3 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare()
#4 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field))
#5 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Container))
#6 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset))
#7 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form))
#8 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#9 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#10 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#11 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#12 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#13 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#15 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#16 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#17 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/NewAction.php(71): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#18 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction->execute()
#19 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#23 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#26 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /path/to/magento/install/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/NewAction/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#29 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#32 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#33 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /path/to/magento/install/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#36 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /path/to/magento/install/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#38 /path/to/magento/install/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Now, from this trace, I can clearly see that some page in the extension is referencing a component called `giftcard_price_selector`, and if i search the source of the extension, i see it referenced in a couple of places.

My question to you is, **how do i figure out which place it is**?

I see that a page is adding a field, which caused magento's internal UI component factory to create a price selector (I assume this is probably a drop-down or something, I'm not really sure.) which is causing the error, but i can't seem to figure out which file it's actually happening in.

Part of this is me wanting to know the answer, but if you post an answer and could give a brief overview of *how* you got the answer so I can learn myself, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there a `.xml` file with: `<uiComponent name="giftcard_price_selector"/>` in it (there could be a space before the last `/` also)? Can you find a file like this:  `ModuleDir/view/adminhtml/ui_component/giftcard_price_selector.xml`?

Comment: nope, all i see in that directory are `giftcard_giftcard_listing.xml` and `giftcard_template_listing.xml`, neither of which contain `giftcard_price_selector` or `giftcard.price.selector` (which is what the block was initially declared as)

Comment: At this point, I'm not aware of a way to use a UI Component without declaring it. Perhaps the dev neglected to include that xml file? When you say that you "see it referenced in a couple of places", what does that mean? Could you provide a few examples?

Comment: Well, when i did a search for it in the source code, i see it in 12 different places. it's in the `Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tag\Attributes\PriceSelectorRender.php` file, in the context of the getPrices method returning `$this->getProduct()->getData('giftcard_price_selector')`, and the `Block\Product\GiftCard.php` returning `return explode(',',$product->getData('giftcard_price_selector'));` for `getSelectorPrice()`, and the setup file in `Setup\InstallData.php`, which adds an attribute called `giftcard_price_selector`, there's too much for comments to fit is. do you want to use IM?

Comment: Interesting. I've not done much work with M2's attributes and rendering - which uses UI Components. However, in `Setup\InstallData.php`,  what is the `'type'` of the `'giftcard_price_selector'` attribute? Or by chance the type is actually: `giftcard_price_selector`?

Comment: Well, if by type you mean the first argument, it's `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY`, if you meant the `type` attribute of the array 3rd argument, it's `varchar`.

Comment: Have you attempted to clear the var/generation directory and the caches to make sure you don't have outdated files in there? var/generation in particular can be problematic when it comes to keeping old files around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the issue should be in a layout.xml file, as that is how UiComponents are included. I would look in your module's `catalog_product_new.xml` file, as that corresponds to the controller name (`Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction`).

That file isn't actually in the stack trace, but Magento reads it from the filesystem to build the tree of layout blocks and containers. In Magento 2, each layout.xml file corresponds to a specific *handle*, which is a term for a set of layout instructions. Typically, the handle corresponds to a action URL (`frontname/controllerFolder/actionName`). In this case, the front name was `catalog`, the controller sub-folder was `product`, and the referenced controller class (which can be called the action class) was `NewController`, so I would look inside the `view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml` file.

Welcome to Magento. Please let me know if anything I said doesn't make sense or needs clarification.

Comment: I don't actually see a catalog_product_new.xml. I searched the source for all the catalog_product xmls and got `/view/adminhtml/layout/giftcard_catalog_product_edit.xml`, `/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`, and `/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_giftcard.xml`

Comment: OK, it looks like the previous developer broke with Magento convention and added their own handles for multiple requests. I'd look in the `adminhtml` and `base` ones.

Comment: I noticed when he declared the price selector WYSIWYG form that the second argument, which i assume is the name, was `giftcard.price.selector` not `giftcard_price_selector`, do you think maybe that's the problem? I'm waiting on it to compile to check

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it either :/

Comment: I'm not super familiar with UiComponents (yet), but the error looks like the issue is with the component itself (like it's missing) rather than the layout. Adding your custom code to the question, or creating a new one (since this one was more about _how_ to debug) is probably a better bet... If you do create a new question, please ping me with the link here and I'll take a look...

Comment: Well, the problem is that it's not necessarily 'my' code, it's a plugin we bought that isn't functional, am i allowed to post samples of that kind of code if i don't have ownership?

Comment: Hmm, that I'm not sure about. If you paid money for the plugin, you should be able to check back with your original developer for support...

Comment: Unfortunately not possible, i don't think, we've tried contacting them and been met with no support or responses from what i can tell. kinda stuck with it i guess.

Comment: What's the license on the extension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50787/discussion-between-zack6849-and-tjons).